# Access file on a remote machine [local network] server [Linux] by URL

Tags: linux, file, remote-access

Lets say a file is saved in Linux server at directory /tmp/someFile. This server resides in local network. I would like to access this file from my working computer [Windows] just typing URL in the browser. What protocol/pattern should URL have?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `/tmp` folder will not be accessible directly from the url . What you can do is you can create a soft link from the `Documentroot` folder to `/tmp` folder .

Assuming `/var/www/html` is your `Documentroot` in apache .You can use the following command to create soft link

```
ln -s /tmp/file /var/www/html/file
```

this will create a soft link directly in the Documentroot folder .This can be accessed directly via the URL.